# How to have a responsive header background with aditional CSS for my theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building my first WordPress website via the Blossom Pin Pro theme and the my background image of the header disappears when the window width.

[Here is the address of the site](http://odetomytravels.com)

If you could write me a code that I can add to the "CSS additional" section of my theme to solve the problem it would be great thank you!

I went through several similar posts and tried different codes, the problem is that I am a beginner in CSS and I can not identify the relevant variables to adjust the code to my site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that your posts [should be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) and [contain minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes sorry I don't know why I wrote in french :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.mobile-header .mobile-site-header {
background-image: url(https://odetomytravels.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Header-2_1.gif);
background-size: cover !important;
background-position: center;
} }
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! You saved me hours of CSS :)

Comment: @Sanjukta Glad to help you! If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted" (check mark) and try to add questions with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time. Have a good day!